# Windows 10 Start menu and TaskBar bugs — tiles/icons disappearing or being replaced by other shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu

Sometimes, some tile of my Windows 10 Start menu simply disappears permanently. The associated shortcut still exists, but it is no longer shown as a tile. If I right-click the shortcut and select "Remove from Start menu", the tile of some other application is removed from the Start menu. This has the tendency to happen after I compress (NTFS compression) a directory where the affected application is located, but also happens on other occasions.

Something similar also happens in the taskbar's pinned icons. For example, the File Explorer icon was suddenly replaced by the shortcut of another application, and clicking it opens that application. I press Win+E to open File Explorer, but it is displayed on the taskbar with the icon of that other application.

Restarting the explorer or Windows doesn't fix it. Updating Windows doesn't solve it, either. This has happened to me, pretty much, in all my Windows 10 installations in different computers. Windows 10 versions doesn't seem to make any difference, as I have the latest version, and this bug has been around for ages. I never installed any software that could be expected to mess with these kinds of things, and this happens even in "stock" Windows 10 installations.

These issues are driving me crazy, as they happen from time to time, and mess up my day-to-day use of Windows 10. I searched the Internet for ages, but couldn't find any solution or anyone with the same issue.

EDIT:
Is there a file or registry key I can edit to try to fix these issues manually?

Comment: The problems you describe are not endemic to Windows 10. There must be some non-compliant software you are installing on your Windows 10 Computers.

Comment: Is there a file or registry key I can edit to try to fix these issues manually?   ...  This is not a Windows issue so no, there is not a Windows fix for the issue

Comment: @John I mean, the Start menu must save the tiles' data somewhere.  Maybe this file has currently some wrong data for some reason, that could be fixed manually?

Comment: My point is that this issue is not a Windows issue so you need to look at what you installed or perhaps have malware on the machine.